# What is a "Seelsmeeting"?

Tags: german-to-english, swiss-german

After missing my call, a Swiss insurance worker texted me that they are in a "Seelsmeeting". When translating this word on Google it says Souls meeting or Spiritual meeting, which makes no sense. What does this word really mean?

Comment: I assume they mean a "sales meeting". The pronounciation of "Seels" is an approximation of how "sales" would be pronounced. Maybe they are trying to be funny?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a German word. I suspect that the insurance clerk typed into their device

> Salesmeeting

But the German spell checker did not know the English part *Sales* of this compound noun and "corrected" it to the best fitting German word *Seele,* which when part of a compound noun becomes either *Seelen-* or *Seels-,* and because of the *s* at the end of *Sales* the program apparently decided on *Seels-.* And so the nonsensical word *Seelsmeeting* was born.

By the way: The English word *meeting* is used in German texts as a loanword (English spelling and almost English pronunciation). However, since it is a noun, the first letter is capitalized in German texts (unless it is part of a compound word and does not come first there).